# How to remove JSON Object from a JSON Array?

Tags: jquery

```
var alldesignationsarr = ['Employee','Manager'];
```

Comment: [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Some example please

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Your question is simply about removing an object (not a "JSON object') from an array (not a "JSON array").

Comment: This is **extremely** well-covered by previous questions and their answers. Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+filter+array+object) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `desgdescarr.filter()`:

```js
var alldesignationsarr = ['Employee','Manager'];

var desgdescarr = [{
    "designation": {
        "name": "Employee",
        "ptest": {}
    },
    
    "designation": {
        "name": "Manager",
        "ptest": {}
    },
    "designation": {
        "name": "Managers",
        "ptest": {}
    }
}];
    
var res = desgdescarr.filter((obj) => alldesignationsarr.indexOf(obj.designation.name) === -1);
console.log(res);
```

If you want to make changes to the original array then you can also use a simple `forEach` logic for that:

```js
var alldesignationsarr = ['Employee','Manager'];

var desgdescarr = [{
    "designation": {
        "name": "Employee",
        "ptest": {}
    },
    
    "designation": {
        "name": "Manager",
        "ptest": {}
    },
    "designation": {
        "name": "Managers",
        "ptest": {}
    }
}];
    
desgdescarr.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(alldesignationsarr.indexOf(obj.designation.name) !== -1){
    desgdescarr.splice(index,1);
  }
});

console.log(desgdescarr);
```